# Customize numeric values in Moment Arabic localization

Tags: localization, momentjs

I want to create my own locale in moment.js, its parent should be the Arabic local but I want only to change to numeric format to display `0-9`, not the default display.

As per documentation, I can start with that:

```js
moment.defineLocale('ar-sa-mine', {
  parentLocale: 'ar-sa',
  /*
     here I need to specify the numeric: change **this ٢٩ to 29**
  */
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at [`locale/ar-sa.js`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.21.0/locale/ar-sa.js) code you will note that moment uses `preparse` and `postformat` to convert from numeric characters to arabic.

You can simply restore default behaviour resetting `preparse` and `postformat` (e.g. see moment code: [`function preParsePostFormat (string) { return string; }`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.21.0/moment.js#L3919))

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment().format() );
console.log( moment().format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY') );

moment.defineLocale('ar-sa-mine', {
  parentLocale: 'ar-sa',
  preparse: function (string) {
    return string;
  },
  postformat: function (string) {
    return string;
  }
});

console.log( moment().format() );
console.log( moment().format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/locale/ar-sa.js"></script>
```