# Display numbers in English while localizing date with other language like Arabic or Hindi using Moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to localize date using moment js but show numbers in English only not any other language.

Suppose I have a date in hindi (hi).

**नव. ३०, २०**

I want to show this as

**नव. 30, 20**

I want this to also work in `FromNow() , calendar() and humanize()` functions too which provide the date in descriptive ways.
for example)

**कल दोपहर ११:१९ बजे**

should be displayed as

**कल दोपहर 11:19 बजे**

Comment: Find the localisation file and update the number localisations to normal one, if you can.

Comment: That might be good for 1 or 2 known languages ,but in my case languages are not predetermined.It'll be set during runtime.

Comment: Ah, it won't work then...

Comment: I think that you can use the solution shown here: [Customize numeric values in Moment Arabic localization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49401205/4131048)

Comment: @VincenzoC Yes that was exactly what I was looking for,thank you so much and would gladly accept your answer if you post it.So that it can help others.

Comment: I'm glad that the other answer helped you, I've put it as duplicate since the answer would be exactly the same of the linked one.

Comment: sure,just a small addition, there the OP was creating a new custom language and here I was trying for existing one so code is almost similar but using different function ```moment.locale('hi', { preparse: function (string) {return string;},postformat: function (string) {return string;}});```

Answer (score 0):

you can customise it [this way](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/). added some comments but you can generally customise everything with regards to text the way you want it. ( set locale to 'en' to display normal numbers)

```
moment.locale('en', {
    // e.g months: "January_febuary_march_april......split('_')
    months : 'janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre'.split('_'),
    monthsShort : 'janv._févr._mars_avr._mai_juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.'.split('_'),
    monthsParseExact : true,
    weekdays : 'dimanche_lundi_mardi_mercredi_jeudi_vendredi_samedi'.split('_'),
    weekdaysShort : 'dim._lun._mar._mer._jeu._ven._sam.'.split('_'),
    weekdaysMin : 'Di_Lu_Ma_Me_Je_Ve_Sa'.split('_'),
    weekdaysParseExact : true,
    longDateFormat : {
        LT : 'HH:mm',
        LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
        L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
        LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
        LLLL : 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
    },
    calendar : {
        sameDay : '[Aujourd’hui à] LT',
        nextDay : '[Demain à] LT',
        nextWeek : 'dddd [à] LT',
        lastDay : '[Hier à] LT',
        lastWeek : 'dddd [dernier à] LT',
        sameElse : 'L'
    },
//the text in [] are generated as it is
    relativeTime : {
        future : 'dans %s', //in %s seconds
        past : 'il y a %s', // %s seconds ago
        s : 'quelques secondes', //a second
        m : 'une minute', //a minute
        mm : '%d minutes', 
        h : 'une heure', //an hour
        hh : '%d heures',
        d : 'un jour', //a day
        dd : '%d jours', //%d days
        M : 'un mois', //a month
        MM : '%d mois', //%d months
        y : 'un an',
        yy : '%d ans'
    },
    dayOfMonthOrdinalParse : /\d{1,2}(er|e)/,
    ordinal : function (number) {
        return number + (number === 1 ? 'er' : 'e');
    },
    meridiemParse : /PD|MD/,
    isPM : function (input) {
        return input.charAt(0) === 'M';
    },
    // In case the meridiem units are not separated around 12, then implement
    // this function (look at locale/id.js for an example).
    // meridiemHour : function (hour, meridiem) {
    //     return /* 0-23 hour, given meridiem token and hour 1-12 */ ;
    // },
    meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
        return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
    },
    week : {
        dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
        doy : 4  // Used to determine first week of the year.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I still can't figure out where can I over-ride the localized numbers with English number.

Comment: u set it as en, and the numbers will be in en

Comment: This might work for known 1 or 2 languages but in my case the working language is not known before hand and that's why its not feasible to customize for all language.

Comment: then again, majority of the languages uses romanise numbers.